# Timed Out Payment Still Unconfirmed After 2 Days?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

On Friday night I tried making a payment of 0.08244000 BTC to a website for some things I had bought, the website used CoinPayments.net for their BTC payments.

I had never used BTC to buy things online before and therefore I didn't realise that I needed to pay miners tax (rookie mistake, I know) and it's now been 2 days and the payment has timed out but is still unconfirmed which means I can't get a refund for my coins.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Do you have a Transaction ID so we can see the details of what happened?

Answer (score -1):

> Can anyone help me out?

nobody can help you. bitcoin is decentralized and no one is responsible for anything.

live with it and try to spend the rest of your life with a principle that **first is learning** and the **second is using** something.

Comment: i understand that, that's not what I'm asking. I was wondering what would happen to the coins, that's what I mean by "help me out".

Comment: there are no "coins" in bitcoin protocol